# using wordpress function is_frontpage() to control supersized slideshow

Tags: wordpress, supersized

iam trying to control supersized slideshow with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleSlideShow(){
      api.playToggle();         
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

//Check frontpage
<?php if (is_front_page() ) { ?>

//not frontpage
<?php } else { ?>

            //call script and pause slideshow!
        <script type="text/javascript">
        ToggleSlideShow();
    </script>       

<?php } ?>
```

But it dosnt work, can anyone please help?

Comment: are you sure you're on frontpage not home - function `is_home()`

Comment: It works if i only load the menu in first statement and not under else, so it should work, maybe.. :-)

Comment: Sry my bad, the problem is that it cant find reference api.playToggle()...

Comment: Javascript runs in the order in which is it outputted. It seems you are trying to run  `ToggleSlideShow();` before `api.playToggle();` is defined. Make sure the order is correct.

Comment: try putting that PHP right before `</body>`

Comment: api.playToggle is defined in <head> should work, i think iam really not sure how to use api.playtoggle! cant find any examples

Comment: same error if i put before </body>

Comment: wait are you not wrapping this with document.ready in your real code?

Comment: Its copy paste from supersized own example "almost" so it should work ?

Comment: "wait are you not wrapping this with document.ready in your real code?" hmm not really that good with javascript, so not sure what you mean sry.

Comment: I've looked at supersized. You can't stop it without mucking about.

Comment: :-) it would explain alot, what you mean with mucking about?

Comment: changing things in a third-party plugin to make it do something it should already do.

Comment: OK thx i think i will just cheat then an load a different header.php (where i load slide) with a different setting!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up :-) instead i just loaded a different header using the if_front_page()